# PHP's DOMDocument appears to not recognize certain HTML entities, how can I include them in my output?

Tags: php, dom

It appears that DOMDocument doesn't recognize certain HTML entities:

```
<?php

$html = '<body>&amp; &bigstar;</body>';
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadHTML($html);
echo $doc->saveHTML($doc->documentElement);
```

https://3v4l.org/rLirt

In the demo code above, the ampersand & (`&amp;`) is encoded correctly, while the star ★ (`&bigstar;`) is converted to `&amp;bigstar;`. The DOMDocument doesn't throw any warnings or errors - it appears to *both* recognize `&bigstar;` as a valid HTML entity *and yet still* convert the leading ampersand into its own HTML entity.

Which HTML entities does the PHP DOM extension with loadHTML not understand? Is there a way to prevent it from turning the openings of these elements into ampersand elements?

Comment: Regular browsers appear to do the same with unknown entities (e.g. &foobar;) so I wouldn't discard that it's what the spec mandates.

Comment: Uuh, I've fallen down a rabbit hole of custom xml entities and I'll get back to you guys once I've come out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `html_entity_decode`

when you save you will save:

```
<html><body>&amp; &amp;bigstar;</body></html>
```

which is correct.
When you get value from node

```
echo $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

you will get:

```
& &bigstar;
```

only entities from that list are allowed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: Oops! `html_entity_decode` was from a version I was experimenting with to get rid of the problem. The actual problem is exactly what you've described as "correct". I don't want the `&bigstar;` to be converted to `&amp;bigstar;`. (The correct version of the code was already in the 3v4l.org paste.)

Comment: why ? You save and after saving you get value exactly the same you put there. Why do you care what's in the XML ?

Comment: Because the value I loaded wasn't `&amp;bigstar;`, it was `&bigstar;`. `&bigstar;` is a valid entity that I want to be preserved in the output.

Comment: `&bigstar;` in scope of XML it's invalid. That's why DOM is converting it to `&amp;bigstar;` it's only valid in HTML

Comment: There appear to be other HTML-only entities that work (such as `&Omega;`). Is there a way to find out which entities are supported?

Comment: seems like `&bigstar;` is just not supported as a official "entity"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141966/discussion-between-alexandr-kapustin-and-marcus-harrison).